# Never ending android background server connection

Tags: android

I have an android app and a server application written in Java. I basically want the app to connect to the server every few seconds to get the newest information, and if neccessary display a push notification, like a Messenger App. I'm new to this, and I've tried multiple ways, but nothing of what I tried seems to work.

I've used a Service which connects to the server every X seconds and gets the newest information from it. The service restarts when It gets destroyed, so it even runs in the background when the app is terminated, but after a while it just stops working and doesn't restart with the error message `Not allowed to start service Intent {snip}: app is in background`. I have no idea if this approach is even a good idea, and I've tried some other things too, but I don't get anywhere, so any advice on how an application like this should be done would be really helpful!

This is my Service class:

```
 public int counter=0;
    public ConnectionService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, BootBroadcastReceiver.class);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();

        initializeTimerTask();

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }


    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                counter++;
                ConnectionManager.oneWayCall(new DebugPacket("Debug Packet: " + counter));
            }
        };
    }
```

I don't neccessarily need help with this exact code, if apps like these should be done in a completely different way, please point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

now you can not run `services` in background forever . system will terminate it after sometime even if you use `foreground service`.

instead of fetching data every x seconds i would recommend ask your backend guy to send data in fcm notification if data is not large.

if you can wait for 15 minutes for  fetching new data you can use `workmanager`.

there is one ugly way of keeping services alive for longer time i will suggest not to use it .
you can start service every x seconds when you receive notification your app is considered in foreground when you receive notification in this window you can start service. catch is you  have to send notifications every x seconds.